# How to center two <div> without them overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center two div elements in the form of buttons. But nothing I try seems to work. The furthest I got is getting it in the middle with `position: absolute;` but when I do that the two  elements get on top of each other.

The code I'm currently using:

```css
/* For the button: */

.btn1 {
  color: #000 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #ed1b36;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 50ms;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}


/* For the hover effect: */

.btn1:hover {
  background: #f2d630;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  box-shadow: 5px 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 50ms;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn1">
    <a class="btn1" href="showTable.php"><b>Reserveringen</b></a>
</div><br>
<div class="btn1">
    <a class="btn1" href="logout.php"><b>Logout</b></a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see both your `div` and your `a` have `btn1` class. Did you used this class as selector in your CSS ? It may be dangerous since styles will be applied to both. I guess this is why they overlap each other, since they have `position: absolute;`.

Comment: Can u add a working example? We don't know which selector your CSS has used

Comment: Please check if my edit shows the selectors you're actually using.

Comment: I did use the class selector btn1 in my CSS. I have removed the class from a but the outcome is still the same. The two <div> elements are still on top of eachother.

Answer (score 1):

Will this help you?

**Added/Edited:** display: block; margin-bottom: 15px;

**Removed:** position: absolute; top:10%; bottom: 10%; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;

```css
.btn1 {
  color: #000 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #ed1b36;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block; /* edited */
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 50ms;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto; /* new */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="btn1" href="showTable.php"><b>Reserveringen</b></a>
  <a class="btn1" href="logout.php"><b>Logout</b></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried using this solution but it doesn't position the two <div> elements to the center of the screen. They arn't on top of eachother anymore though!

Comment: Change the margin-bottom to **margin: 0 auto 15px auto;**. I've updated the snippet!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. i have use `margin-right:auto` and `margin-left:auto` for btn1 to align it horizontally center and

`.btns{
  margin-top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%)
  }`

to align it center vertically

```css
.btn1 {
  color: #000 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #ed1b36;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 50ms;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-bottom:10px;

}
.btn1:hover {
  background: #f2d630;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  box-shadow: 5px 40px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
  transition: all 0.3s ease 50ms;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.btns{
  margin-top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%)
  }
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <a class="btn1" href="showTable.php"><b>Reserveringen</b></a>
  <a class="btn1" href="logout.php"><b>Logout</b></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Getting closer! My buttons are centered horizontally now, but not vertically.
It also cropped my background.
Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: i didn't get you can you plz update the code. so i can understand it better. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how to link proper looking code on stackoverflow so I will do it with a pastebin link:

https://pastebin.com/RgNf5cXm

Comment: I'm trying to center the buttons horizontally and vertically.

Its looking like this at the moment:

https://gyazo.com/87cac38f79f5ffd4f0386a292791205c

Comment: but in snippet it is working properly. can you please share the jsfiddle link of full code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v501wnsm/ 

I have updated the snippet.

The result of the code is looking like this: 

https://gyazo.com/74d648a3dc1f77280f93e0e4bfa5957a

Answer (score 0):

If you need to horizontally center `a` inside of a `div` your `div` should have a `text-align: center`.

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/03t46hmn

Please note:
Using a same class for `div` and `a` may cause confusion. Try to avoid such approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am currently using the text-align: center to get the a inside of the div in the center of it. But I'am trying to figure out how to do the same for both <div> elements

Comment: P.s I have tried to use the fiddle but it still doesnt center the buttons horizontally and vertically. I'm not using any other code to change something in my body as far as I'm concerned

Comment: Then I think it will be very good if you can attach an image of how you expect things to look like. I will be able to update fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should style each tag div. Set different left for each tag div.
Such as

```
<div class="btn1">
  <a class="btn1" href="showTable.php"><b>Reserveringen</b></a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="btn1 btn-logout">
  <a class="btn1" href="logout.php"><b>Logout</b></a>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.btn-logout{
    left: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="con">
  <div class="btn1">
    <a class="btn1" href="showTable.php"><b>Reserveringen</b></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn1">
    <a class="btn1" href="logout.php"><b>Logout</b></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.con{
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* here you can also use space-around or center */
  align-items: center; /* this will align then center horizontally */
}
.btn1{
  /* style the button as you like */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Tried this solution but the results are the same for me

Comment: I've edited the code. add align-content: center if you want to center your elements vertically.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Seinfeld/pen/pqmbgV check this if this is what you want